# referring a global string variable in UIViewController Extension

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, extension-methods

Let's say there is a global string variable in a ViewController class. Within another extension file (ViewControllerExtension.swift) of this ViewController class, I want to be able to make adjustments to this global variable within a function.

Right now, there is a function in the extension which takes the global string variable as an input :

```
func doSomething(inputString: String){
//something is being done and the adjustment will be reflected in the ViewController instance.
}
```

My question is:

1. Is there a way for get access to the ViewController's global string variable without having to refer it by going through a function as it's input?
2. What would be a good designed way to go about this? How would a seasoned programmer go about solving this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you should do is use a the didSet method of a variable, 
it goes something like this:

```
var Name = "" {
    didSet{
        print("The name has been change")
    }
}
```

Now with that in mind you could say

```
class Your_class {
    var Name = "" {
        didSet{
            //something is being done and the adjustment will be reflected in the ViewController instance.
        }
    }

}

extension Your_class {
   self.Name = "Paco"
}
```

Now this will actually do the same thing, it is a little bit more appropriate for swift but at the end what you are doing seems fine. the problem that  I see in your code is that if you call that function or even what I just posted and the VC is not on the screen this won't work, if that is the case please post more info so we can help you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite confused about what are you trying to achieve but, you are not defining a global variable. A global variable is difined out side of your view controller scope, so what you can access it from anywhere in your project.

Personnally, I don't think a global variable is necessary. There are so many ways Apple provided to pass data around. You can pass data from a view controller to another by using segue or unwind. You can also have a delegate to broadcast function calls. You can also use notification center to do so. Unless it's absolutely needed, I do not suggest you to use a global variable.